# SSMS expand specific database

Tags: ssms, ssms-2017

I have 1 database on a server that is hosting hundreds of databases, is there a way to connect to and expand only my database rather than expanding databases and seeing all of them?

Please note that this is on a server at GoDaddy, that I don't have admin access to.

Answer (score 1):

By default, every user has the [VIEW ANY DATABASE Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms189077(v=sql.105)). You can deny it. After that, the user can only see the databases that the user actually owns.

deny VIEW ANY DATABASE
[image]

result
[image]

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or later, you can consider using the contained database feature. A contained database is a database that is isolated from other databases and from the instance of SQL Server that hosts the database. Therefore users will be able to connect to a contained database without authenticating a login at the Server-Level. Please refer to [Contained Databases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-2017).

Comment: In any other situation this would be a great answer, but this is a GoDaddy database server to which I don't have admin rights. I am surprised they give view database permissions to all users.

Comment: @beso9595 Please stick to Markdown wherever possible instead of using HTML